# Hot to simplify $(1-\frac{1} {N} )(1-\frac{2} {N} )...(1-\frac{r-1} {N} )$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to figure out the algebraic simplification from step $6$ to $7$ [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27956609?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents)

Specifically the left side:

$(1-\frac{1} {N} )(1-\frac{2} {N} )...(1-\frac{r-1} {N} )$

To **that**:

$1-(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{2}{N} +... +\frac{r-1}{N}) +...$

I tried to multiply out but can't see how they got it and what are the terms after the last three dots.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it could be tackled by induction over $r$.

Comment: Sorry ;) Do you then have that $$(1-\frac{1}{N})(1-\frac{2}{N})...(1-\frac{r-1}{N})=1-(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{2}{N}+...+\frac{r-1}{N})\color{red}\ldots$$? What do you mean by $\color{red}\ldots$?

Comment: @B.Swan it's algebraic simplification. Nothing to do with induction. I don't want to prove I just want to understand the step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you give, Frederick Mosteller writes:

> If we multiply out the left-hand side of Equation (6) to terms of order $1/N$ [...]

So let us do that. Here at do it step by step to show the process, and write "..." for terms that are at least quadratic in $1/N$:
$$\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{1}N\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{N}\right)\cdots &\left(1-\frac{r-1}{N}\right)
= {\color{red}1}\cdot\left(1-\frac{2}{N}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{r-1}{N}\right)-{\color{red}{\frac{1}{N}} }\left(1-\frac{2}{N}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{r-1}{N}\right)\\
&= \left(1-\frac{2}{N}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{N}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{r-1}{N}\right)-\frac{1}{N} + \dots\\
&= \left(1-\frac{3}{N}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{r-1}{N}\right)
- \frac{2}{N} \left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{r-1}{N}\right)-\frac{1}{N} + \dots\\
&= \left(1-\frac{3}{N}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{r-1}{N}\right)
- \frac{2}{N} + \dots -\frac{1}{N} + \dots\\
&= \left(1-\frac{3}{N}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{r-1}{N}\right)
- \frac{2}{N} -\frac{1}{N} + \dots\\
& \vdots\\
&= \left(1-\frac{r-1}{N}\right) - \frac{r-1}{N} - \cdots
- \frac{2}{N} -\frac{1}{N} + \dots\\
&= 1 - \left(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{2}{N}+\cdots+\frac{r-1}{N}\right) - \dots
\end{align*}$$
as claimed.

Basically, what it is doing is expanding the $(r-1)$-term product (there are $2^{r-1}$ terms), and only showing the term $1=\underbrace{1\cdot1\cdots 1}_{r-1\text{ times}}$ and the $r-1$ terms of the form $-\frac{k}{N}$ (obtained by multiplying $r-2$ factors being $1$, and one being $-\frac{k}{N}$).

Comment: Thank you, so after the last three dots will come the products right?

Comment: @Deb.U Yes, you''ll have terms like $a/N^2$, $b/N^3$, etc.

Comment: Can you explain how you got from product of $\frac{1} {N}(1-\frac{2}{N})$ in line 2. To sum line 5: $-frac{1} {N}+...$.i didn't understand how from product u got sum.

Comment: @Deb.U you have $$(1/N)(1-2/N)\cdots(1-(r-1)/N) = (1/N-2/N^2)(1-3/N)\cdots(1-(r-1)/N)=(1/N-\dots)(1-4/N)\cdots(1-(r-1)/N)=(1/N-\dots)(1-5/N)\cdots(1-(r-1)/N)$$ and so on. The only $1/N$ terms comes from $1/n \cdot 1\cdot 1\cdots 1$, all other terms where expanding have $1/N^k$ for $k\geq 2$.

Comment: Sorry I've lost you.. I'll try to read it again. Can't see how it went from the product to sum.

Comment: @Deb.U By expanding the product. Try with an example, say $r=4$. $$\frac{1}{N}\left(1-\frac{2}{N}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{N}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{N}-\frac{2}{N^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{N}\right)=\frac{1}{N}-\frac{3}{N^2}-\frac{2}{N^2}+\frac{6}{N^4} = \frac{1}{N}+\dots$$

Comment: Got it! BTW, can u tell me how they got from step 7 to step 8? It's ok if it's too much for you. I saw they multiple by N and canceled the ones but there are term after the three dots. Can't see how they neglected them.

Comment: @Deb.U I don't have access to the source anymore (I am no longer in my university, and it's behind a paywall).

Comment: Oh sorry for that. Well I'll try to figure it out if not, maybe I'll put it as an addition in my question.

Comment: @Deb.U You may also start a new question and link to that one.

Answer (score 1):

In the article the birthmate problem is compared with birthday problem. In step $6$ it is obtained:
$$(1-\frac{1} {N} )(1-\frac{2} {N} )...(1-\frac{r-1} {N} )=\left(1-\frac1N\right)^n$$
Next it is stated:

> If we multiply out the left-hand side of Equation $(6)$ to terms of order $1/N$, and
>   expand the right-hand side to two terms we get:
>   $$1-(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{2}{N} +... +\frac{r-1}{N}) +\cdots=1-\frac1N+\cdots$$

Indeed, for the left side, consider simpler cases to see the pattern (up to the term $1/N$):
$$\begin{align}(1-\frac{1} {N} )(1-\frac{2} {N} )&=1-\frac1N-\frac2N+\frac{1\cdot 2}{N^2};\\
(1-\frac{1} {N} )(1-\frac{2} {N} )(1-\frac{3} {N} )&=\left(1-\frac1N-\frac2N+\frac{1\cdot 2}{N^2}\right)(1-\frac{3} {N} )=\\
&=1-\frac1N-\frac2N-\frac3N+\frac{1\cdot 2}{N^2}+\frac{1\cdot 3}{N^2}+\frac{2\cdot 3}{N^2}-\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}{N^3};\end{align}$$
For the right side, the binomial theorem is used (up to two terms):
$$\left(1-\frac1N\right)^n=1-\frac{n}{1}\cdot \frac1N+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot \frac1{N^2}-\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks , your answer helped me too to understand everything. Together with @Clement C. Answer.

Comment: You are welcome. If it was helpful, you can upvote both accepted and my answers. Good luck.